# How to disable radio button after a time interval

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my php script function

```
$xRadio = 0;<br>
echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js'><br>   </script>";
echo"<script type='text/javascript'> 
 $xRadio = setInterval(function(){ $('.radio').attr('disabled',true);},3000);
</script>";
```

and here is the radio button which i want to disable in php

```
echo "<td><input type='radio' class='radio' name='$i' value='A'>" . $row['opt_a'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: You can't interact html ( front-end ) with php ( back-end ) after the code has been generated. You need to add `JavaScript` code for that.

Comment: To add something about the comment of @DainisAbols ; Php run once before sending the "html" to the browser. It won't work anymore until you change page or make an Ajax(Javascript) call. So his suggestion of using Javascript (or Jquery) is the correct one.

Comment: @DainisAbols Hence the JavaScript code, within PHP's echo, I think.

Comment: Hence, wrong title :)

Comment: @DainisAbols The OP is a little mixed up, granted :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `setTimeout()`, you only need to call the function once. Wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` function, as I'm not sure the DOM is ready when you are running this script. Use jQuery's `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $xRadio = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.radio').prop('disabled',true);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Excuse me if I don't add your PHP as well, but it is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: i have added the same code but it is also not working, my file in which i am writing the code is .php extension and i don't know why javacripts is not working in this file.i am very new for php so can you help me, do you have any code for this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try out this modified code.

```
 echo "<td><input type='radio' class='radio' name='$i' value='A'>" . $row['opt_a'] . "</td>";
    $xRadio = 0;echo "<br>";

    echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js'><br>   </script>";
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'> 
    setInterval(function(){ $('.radio').attr('disabled',true);},3000);</script>";
```